# C++ compiler output is not running due to permisson error

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following make file:

```
CC=g++

CFLAGS=-c -Wall

1: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) 03_datatypes.cpp -o program
    ./program
```

and as you can see I am trying to run the `program` file after compiling. I am getting the following error:

```
 make: execvp: ./program: Permission denied
 makefile:7: recipe for target '1' failed
 make: *** [1] Error 127
```

I was using makefiles like this before on a different computer but never faced this issue before.

As suggested by someone below: 
I tried to `chmod +x program` but I am getting a different error

```
 bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: It is possible that the 'program'  does not have executable attribute set on the file. Did you run compilation on a file system that is mounted with noecex option or on some other unusual file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CFLAGS:

```
   CFLAGS=-c -Wall
```

tell the compiler to produce a .o file (which you then rename with the -o option), but not to link it. And .o files are not executable. Remove the `-c` option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on a linux system and do not have execute permission set on the `program` binary.

Before you try to run the program, give it execute permissions by `chmod +x program`.

Comment: I tried but I am getting a different error `bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`